# Exporting .FBX model into XNA - unorthogonal bones

Tags: xna, 3dsmax, fbx

I create a butterfly model in 3ds max with some basic animation, however trying to export it to .FBX format I get the following exception.. any idea how i can transform the wings to be orthogonal..

One or more objects in the scene has local axes that are not perpendicular to each other (non-orthogonal). 
The FBX plug-in only supports orthogonal (or perpendicular) axes and will not correctly import or export any transformations that involve non-perpendicular local axes. 
This can create an inaccurate appearance with the affected objects: 
    -Right.Wing

I have attached a picture for reference . . .

[image: Butterfly 3D model]

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the error message implies that you performed scaling on some of the bones.

You could try to do an XForm reset on the bones and/or reset the scale of the pivot from the Hierarchy panel.
(I don't rig much though, I don't know if either of these will work as intended for bones)

If that doesn't help, I suppose you can try to recreate the bones and make sure not to scale them after creating them.

Comment: The problem now is if i try to scale them again the skin is attached n gets stretched too . . Is there any sure shot way that the next model i would create will work in XNA?